# Android: Does 'Complie With' cause "There is a problem_parsing the package" error?

Tags: android, sdk, compilation, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-2.1-eclair

So I made an App on Android, I compiled it with Android 4.1(4.2 JB), when I uploaded it onto a friends mobile (Xperia X8 with 2.1), I got 'There is a problem parsing the package', so I went to Manifest file and changed the versions to

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="2"
android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
```

Does this not change anything? Should I redo the whole app with 'Compile With' set to 2.1? Any solutions?

If that isn't the problem, a guy just told me that the problem is on my package name. Hell, I don't understand why he thinks that package name has anything to do with the error at all. I've seen various Android Apps with different package names, mostly its reversed domains of the developer.

I used `in.iman.mynewapp` , he argues its because my friends are in Canada and Serbia it won't work, I'll have to use `com.iman.mynewapp`. I know this looks stupid, but just wanted to clarify if package name has nothing to do with errors, its just like a variable name (with its own naming protocols alone), aint it?

I've asked the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684100/receiving-porblem-parsing-the-package-in-phone

It still awaits any reply or comment at all, maybe it was a very poorly framed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the package name indeed doesnt have any relation with the country. The application compiled against android 4.2 might not work just by changing the `minSdkVersion`. You should also make sure that when the min sdk version is dropped you are not getting any compile error. The new versions of android have new API's that were not present in lower version.

To summarize
I would suggest re-compiling against android 2.1 . This way you can also make sure that all the codes are compilable for that particular version of Android.

On a side note android 2.1 is api level 7 and android 4.2 is api level 17 so you can also try this:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="7"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

You can find the list of Api level for different android OS versions [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: Thank you. But if there are problems with only APIs then it should be a run time error, that is what bothers me. I'll recomplie with 2.1 and let you know.

Comment: By the way why did you change the target sdk as well. The target can still be jelly bean , you just need to change the min sdk version to get it running on eclair 2.1.

Comment: Well, the SDK versions were this by default, had minSdkVersion at 8, it didn't work for him. So I changed it to 7,6,5,4,3,2 and doesn't work. Changed the targetSdkVersion in a wild goose chase. Thanks for letting me know though.

Answer (score 0):

This may be occur due to reasons that apk file is compatible to your android phone only.It can be due to security reasons that unknown file cant be installed.So changing Manifest file works if the problem is due to android version otherwise get access for unknown files from security option.

Comment: We have 'Unknown apps'/'Non-market apps' checked in Device administration.  It sadly, isnt the source of the problem. Thanks.